# Sorting GridView in Universal Windows Platform

Tags: c#, gridview, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I want to sort items in my GridView.

My GridView looks like:

```
<GridView x:Name="ivGridView" Margin="70,40,10,10" SelectionChanged="ivGridView_SelectionChanged">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,10"  Width="121" Height="128" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#19000000">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Image}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="88" Margin="0,0,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
                        <Image.RenderTransform>
                            <CompositeTransform ScaleX="1.2" ScaleY="1.2"/>
                        </Image.RenderTransform>
                    </Image>
                    <StackPanel Background="{Binding Color}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding wpn}" Foreground="White" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding sname}" Foreground="White" Margin="7,0,0,0" FontWeight="Light" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
```

How can I sort them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to @Filip's idea, I will show you the detailed information about how to sort the Items in the GridView.

For example you want to sort the GridView Items based on the first letter of the TextBlock text which has been binded to the **wpn**, then we need to define the following class for data binding first:

```
 public class Test
{
    public BitmapImage Image { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush Color { get; set; }
    public string wpn { get; set; }
    public string sname { get; set; }
}
```

After that we can use the [OrderBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.100).aspx) method of the ObservableCollection to sort the ListView by the first letter of the **wpn** column and bind the ObservableCollection to the ItemsSource of the GridView as following:

```
 public ObservableCollection<Test> TestOC = new ObservableCollection<Test>();
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        TestOC.Add(new Test() {wpn="BB",sname="BBB",Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Capture.PNG")),Color=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)});
        TestOC.Add(new Test() { wpn = "CC", sname = "CCC", Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Capture.PNG")), Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green) });
        TestOC.Add(new Test() { wpn = "AA", sname = "AA", Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Capture.PNG")), Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange) });
        var SortResult = TestOC.OrderBy(a => a.wpn);           
        ivGridView.ItemsSource =SortResult;
    }
```

The result:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of a *List*, probably better choice would be *ObservableCollection*, which would allow to sort items at any time, not only before setting it as *ItemsSource*.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Using the ObservableCollection could be a better choice. 
And I have updated my answer. :), Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't show how you can sort an `ObservableCollection` without having to keep setting the `ItemsSource`, which is often _not_ ideal. +1 if this question can be answered more thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the associated `ItemsSource` to sort the items in the view.